# Div not fully loading using .click(function() but does once browser is resized

Tags: jquery, loading

**Website**
http://mgaco.com/newhome/

I'm having an issue with a hidden div fully loading when triggered by an .click(function().

I've researched the issue and tried both $(document).ready(function() and window.onload. Neither has resolved my issue.

**NOTE: The div displays correctly when resizing the browser.** or intermittently after waiting a few seconds.

**Display Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.client-logos').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
});
</script>
```

**Trigger Code**

```
<script>

$(".client-logo-container").hide();
$(".work-button").click(function(){
$(".client-logo-container").slideToggle(1000);
});
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the problem / question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is just the Slick library you are using. From my (somewhat minimal) testing it seems to update its layout every time the slides change or the page is resized. You may want to have the div visible (`display: block` or something) but with a height of 0.

The same problem is visible if you just run `$(".client-logo-container").show();` instead of doing the animation.

Comment: Thanks Ben, As you first said "I think the problem is just the Slick library you are using" 

I tried another script and its working as expected. 
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Thanks for your help!.

Shane